# Reload website once for specific window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I want load a specific function only for window sizes under `1000px`. This generally works, but not if I change the window size, and do not reload the page. So I thought I could code a specific point when the website reloads, so then this function only appears under a window size of `1000px`.

This is my try:

```js
if ($(window).width() = 1000) {
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    this.location.href = this.location.href;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Page should reload once if the window size has 1000px.</span>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Why? Could somebody help me please? <3

Comment: When your javascript runs, it evaluates the window width at runtime. If you want to check the width when the screen is resized, you need to put your check inside the resize event listener.

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch – Interesting. But I still don't know how to do it. Could show it to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps.

I first add an event listener to the resize event. I check the width of the window, and the url for a query string that would suggest we have already been redirected. If the width is over 1000 and we have been redirected, I remove the query string from the url. If we have not run before, and our width is 1000 or below, I redirect us to the same page, however I add a query string so the function can see we should not redirect again. This prevents the page from loading too many times as the resize event fires quite a few times when manually being resized.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        const widthAbove1000 = window.innerWidth > 1000;

        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        let noRun = urlParams.get('noRun');

        if (widthAbove1000 && noRun)
          window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0];

        if (widthAbove1000 || noRun) return;

        window.location.href = window.location.href + "?noRun=true";
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are genious! 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with .resize() method from jQuery and change "=" to "<=", [link to w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

As jQuery docs says:

> The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 1000) {
    this.location.href = this.location.href;
  }
});
```

Comment: instead of being `=== 1000` it should likely be `< 1000` because the odds of you getting the event firing at exactly 1000 px is low

Comment: My concern with this answer is that you will reload every time the page is resized below 1000, where you probably only want it to reload when it goes above 1000 or below. I am thinking adding a query string to the redirect, checking, and removing when it gets larger.